# Cannot redirect role's view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, roles

I have these codes here for the Login POST and GET

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Account/Login

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
        {
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }


        if (User.IsInRole("Owner"))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "AdminOnly");
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return View(model);
    }
```

My problem, however, is that when I try to login an admin account, I get redirect to the ~/Shared/Layout. What should I do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your first `if` statement redirects you if its valid. Your never reach the second `if` (which I assume is what your expecting to do if the user is "Owner")

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I read an answer by @KurtSchindler in this same forum. This code block works like a charm

```
  if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
        {
            string[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(model.UserName);
            if (roles.Contains("Owner") || roles.Contains("Superuser"))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "AdminOnly");
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
```

It is now redirecting me to the Index inside the AdminOnly controller. Hope this helps! And thanks!

Comment: What? You have taken my exact answer and repeated it. Good luck with future questions

Answer (score 0):

Your first `if` statement immediately redirects the user if valid. You never get to check their role since you have already exited the method. Change your method to test the users role before redirecting

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
  {
    if (User.IsInRole("Owner"))
    {
      return RedirectToAction("Index", "AdminOnly");
    }
    else
    {
      return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }
  }
  ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
  return View(model);
}
```

Comment: It still redirects me to the /_Layout.cshtml

Comment: What do you mean it redirects to `~/Shared/_Layout`? That's a layout (master page) not a view. What is the value of `returnUrl` when you post. What is in the `Index.cshtml` view of `AdminOnly` controller? Debug your code and see where your actually redirecting to.

Comment: This is the index of the AdminOnly controller:                                   `[Authorize(Roles = "Owner")]
        [ActionName("Index")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.UserProfiles.ToList());
        }`

Comment: The method signature is irrelevant. Show the view - `/Views/AdminOnly/Index.cshtml` (assuming your have debugged it and that's the one your hitting). And edit you question with new code - dont put in comments